# How to pass JWT token from one activity to another?

Tags: android, kotlin, jwt

I have the following onCreate class in MainActivity and proven to be able to work with my server. It is able to extract out the JWT token

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    submitButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_submit)

    // Volley code is here
    val url = "http://192.168.1.8:4000"

    submitButton.setOnClickListener({
        val pinCode = pin_code.text.toString()
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val params = HashMap<String, String>()
        params.put("pin_code", pinCode)
        val request = object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url + "/api/employees/token", JSONObject(params),
                Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
                    val token = response
                            .getJSONObject("data")
                            .getString("token")

                    val myIntent = Intent(this, SiteActivity::class.java)
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0)
                },
                Response.ErrorListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }){
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json")
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                return headers
            }
        }
        queue.add(request)
        queue.start()
    })
}
```

Unfortunately I have not figured out a way to add the JWT token into the authorized bearer Header for the next SiteActivity. Any suggestion how to make this work? Should I pass the token directly to the next activity or should I use a singleton? Thanks!

Comment: that's not the way to make a request in our generation ;) use retrofit: http://square.github.io/retrofit/
it solved all you issues

Comment: @itzhar how would you do it? I see the documentation there are no examples of using JWT

Comment: Pass the JWT in some @Header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Straightly answering question

Put data into Intent with [putExtra("token", token)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Take it on the other side with getIntent().[getStringExtra("token")](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)).

## But...

You may want to save token persistently. For example, into SharedPreferences.